# How to match CAPS LOCK in vimrc file of VIM

Tags: vim, capslock

As we map different keys in `.vimrc` file of vim. I want to map Caps lock. As back space we write `<BR>` or for Enter `<CR>` what is the representation of Caps lock in `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 4):

As you can see in `:help key-notation`, you can't map that key in Vim.

You need to do it at the system level and how to do that depends on your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding me. Hope for further guidance when required.